# Paging toolbar extjs how fix the position of a tooltip

Tags: extjs

I'm working on ExtJS grid(extjs 6.6.0.258) and using Paging Toolbar for the grid. 
Can I fix the position of a tooltip for a button(next, prev and etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace default parameters [refreshText](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.toolbar.Paging.html#cfg-refreshText), nextText, prevText, lastText and etc texts for `pagingtoolbar` to [qtip](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tip.QuickTip.html) config object and with help [anchor](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tip.QuickTip.html#cfg-anchor) property set needed position

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33gi) (look at refresh button)